# iPhone / Android Web App

Tags: iphone, android, mobile-website

So I'm starting to design a Web App for mobile. This is my first mobile Web App, BTW. I'm very used to writing Web Apps for desktop: C#, jQuery, JSON, etc.

On the server-side, I'll stick to C#. But I'm curious about the client-side.

I have some questions on the subject:

- Are there any guidelines for mobile web development?
- What should I worry about for mobile?
- I see there's a [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/). Nice! Can anyone give me a feedback on that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your target device range? high end? all?

Comment: iPhone, Andriod, Blackberry. High End mostly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used both [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) and JQmobile. I like JQuery mobile myself better, but I'm just waiting for a release. Unfortunately, If you run the demos on your phone (I have the original Droid) they seem pretty slow and buggy. On my PC though, they run great. So I'm curious about the other tools out there.